# Не происходит асинхронное выполнение

Tags: python, nginx, асинхронность, gunicorn

Не происходит асинхронное выполнение запросов. Получение запросов

```
from flask import request, render_template
from app import app_flask, token_flask, forms
from analytical import database


@app_flask.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
async def api_request():
    token_api = request.json['token']
    repository_path = request.json['repository_path']
    instance_db_client = database.DataBaseHandler()
    print('db-', type(instance_db_client.get_report))
    return await instance_db_client.get_report(repository_path, token_api)


@app_flask.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
async def main_page():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = forms.RepositoryPathForm()
        return render_template('index.html', form=form), 200
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.RepositoryPathForm()
        repository_path = request.form['link_repository']
        instance_db_client = database.DataBaseHandler()
        json, code = await instance_db_client.get_report(repository_path, token_flask)
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, json=json), code


@app_flask.errorhandler(404)
async def page_not_found(error):
    return 'Страницы не существует!!', 404
```

Обращение к постороннему серверу, предполагаю где то тут ошибка

```
    async def link(self):
        try:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                async with session.post(url=self.url, headers=self.headers, json=self.json) as resp:
                    data = json.loads(await resp.read())
                return data
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            logger.error(f'ERROR500! Ошибка ссоединения с сервером. Исключение: {e}')
            resp_json.query_info.code = 500
            resp_json.query_info.error_desc = 'ConnectionError'
            resp_json.query_info.error_message = str(e)
```

Тестирую на сервере debian, запущено через nginx и gunicorn.
Для теста запускаю gunicorn с одним worker'ом.
Программа выполняется в синхронном режиме, пока запрос не пройдет другие запросы не принимает.
Возможно что то нужно настроить в gunicorn или nginx, но я к сожалению не нашел. При запуске в отладочном режиме выдает ошибку (но продолжает работать)

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000285CD08FF40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vi812\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\vi812\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\vi812\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\vi812\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Что означает «не происходит», что происходит вместо того, что вы ожидаете?

Comment: @andreymal, отправляю запрос время обработки которого допустим 90 секунд, в эти 90 секунд сервер не будет отвечать даже на обращения к главной странице

Comment: Тогда это нормально, потому что Flask принципиально не асинхронный, меняйте его на какой-нибудь другой асинхронный веб-фреймворк

Comment: @andreymal, flask ведь работает с asyncio... или чего я не понимаю?

Comment: Работает, но асинхронным всё равно не является

Comment: @andreymal во фласке вроде прицепили эвентлуп в полгода назад... Надо глянуть стартер.

Comment: @eri не знаю что было полгода назад, но в документации до сих пор прям так написано «Each request still ties up one worker, even for async views.»

Comment: Тогда советую переходить на Quart

Comment: @andreymal похоже перепутал с другим сервером. В последнее время aiohttp достаточно... Не особо воспринимаю что там у других

Comment: Благодарю! Пробую перевести на Sanic, посмотрим что выйдет.

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю! Как же дорого мне обошлось это тайное знание... Переделал на Sanic, все работает))

Answer (score 0):

Хоть вы и используете корутины, вся это асинхронность работает в контексте синхронного фреймворка. Здесь смысл асинхронности насколько я понимаю, чтобы в контексте одного запроса получить возможность асинхронно запускать различные функции(получение данных с бд и допустим еще какие-то задачи ввода вывода). Но в целом запросы не обрабатываются асинхронно